# Why can't object refer to parent object and child object?

Tags: kotlin, object, oop, nodes

Look, I'm facing this basic problem where I want to construct sort of nodes where node is a category and it could have parent category and list of it's children categories, I just realized that it's impossible in OOP or am I wrong? I can handle my case in a way that each object will have only list of its children but then I'll have to (in my opinion) unnecessarily filter through all of the categories to find it's parent here is a basic idea of problem I'm facing

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your constructors require the parent and child to be constructed before the current object can be constructed. That is impossible in your case as the references form a dependency cycle (`First` -> `Fourth` -> `Third` -> `Second` -> `First`, therefore `First` can't be fully created till after `First` is created, etc.).

One solution would be to make the `Node` abstract (or an interface) and only fetch the values when they are requested (i.e. in the getters):

```kotlin
interface Node {
    val number: Int
    val parent: Node?
    val child: Node?
}

object First : Node {
    override val number = 1
    override val parent get() = Fourth
    override val child get() = Second
}

// Similar for Second, Third, and Fourth
```

---

If you're interested in why you got that particular pattern of nulls, it's important to remember that objects in Kotlin usually aren't created till the first time they are used.

1. The first object you use (in `main`) is `First`, so it's constructor is called.
2. The first* thing its constructor does is get a reference to `Fourth`, which in turn does `Third`, which in turn does `Second`, which in turn tries to do `First`, but `First` is already in the process of being created, so its reference is `null`.
3. Then (we're still in `Second`) it tries to create `Third` (as the `child`), which is in the process of being created, so its reference is also `null`. At this point `Second` is done, so any future reference to it will not be `null`.
4. `Third` now has a valid reference to `Second`, and moves on to trying to create `Fourth`, which is still being created, thus `null`. Now `Third` is done.
5. `Fourth` now has a valid reference to `Third`, and moves on to `First`, which is still being created, thus `null`. Now `Forth` is done.
6. `First` now has a valid reference to `Fourth`, and moves on to `Second`, which already exists and is valid. Now `First` is done.

**Technically the second, since the first thing it does is set the number, but it's the first thing that matters for the purposes of this discussion.*